# Passing a string pointer to a function running on different thread in C++ and Xcode 11.1

Tags: c++, xcode, multithreading, stdthread

I'm trying to run the following simple example.

```
void printString(const char* s)
{
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
      std::string str = "hello world";
      std::thread T3(printString, str.c_str());
}
```

But I get the following error.

```
No matching constructor for initialization of 'std::thread'
```

I'm using Xcode 11.1.

If this were to compile, would this code even work? Since threads share the same heap, thread `T3` should be able to access `str.c_str()` right? Assuming that `std::string` buffers are allocated on the heap.

Thanks!

Comment: No, this code will not work. It's almost a guaranteed crash.

Comment: Thanks. So, how can I pass a string from the main thread to a child thread?

Comment: Start with figuring out the compilation error. The shown code compiles without issues for me, once I add all the missing includes. Then, you have to make sure that the string/pointer, whatever being passed to the new thread is valid. This is what you were getting to in your question. But your `main()` returns immediately, there's no guarantee that the string will still exist when the new execution thread starts. This is a guaranteed crash anyway, since you must `join()` a new execution thread before its `std::thread` gets destroyed, which happens when `main()` returns.

Comment: To avoid the crash, pass the string by value.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use std::thread you need to include a proper header file. Then you must decide to wait for the thread to do its job or to detach it. Otherwise std::thread will call std::terminate in a destructor. Another problem is that you will have a dangling pointer in a printString function if main returns and releases a string.

So, one possible solution

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void printString(const char* s)
{
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
      std::string str = "hello world";
      std::thread T3(printString, str.c_str());
      T3.join();
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code does not compile. I get the same exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by setting my CMake to use C++ 11

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

The generated Xcode project now has the right compiler flags set and the posted code compiles correctly.